# Re-evaluate LINQ query when ObservableCollection changes

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-objects, observablecollection

I have a common issue that I'd like to (hopefully) find a better solution for moving forward.  I have an ObservableCollection containing a master list of data.  In my client code I need to 'transform' the data into a new form for display to the user.  I use a LINQ statement like:

```
var newList = (from item in observable
               select new { FirstInitial = item.Name[0] });
```

I know it's pretty rudimentary but it is enough to demonstrate the problem.  (Notice the projection, this is not a simple filter or grouping statement.)  I then display newList in my UI via data-binding.

Problem is, when the original collection changes, the UI doesn't.  The solution I've applied thus far has been to attach an event handler to the original collection's CollectionChanged event which re-evaluates the query and updates the bound property.

While this works fine, it's a lot of repeated code every time I run across this scenario.  Is there a way that I can have the LINQ query return an ObservableCollection that "automatically" updates when the source Observable is changed?

In other words, I'd like to implement some 'canned' functionality so I can simply reuse it whenever I have this scenario.

UPDATE

Thanks to Scroog1 for helping me see my original post was too coupled to the UI for what I was really asking.  Take the following example as a better description of the problem:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    private ObservableCollection<Employee> _allEmployees;
    private ObservableCollection<Employee> _currentEmployees;

    public ObservableCollection<Employee> CurrentEmployees
    {
        get
        {
            if (_currentEmployees == null)
                _currentEmployees = _allEmployees.Where(e => !e.IsTerminated);

            return _currentEmployees;
        }
    }
}

public class SomeViewModel
{
    private ICollectionView _view;

    public ICollectionView CurrentView
    {
        if (_view == null)
        {
            var cvs = new CollectionViewSource()
            {
                Source = someClass.CurrentEmployees
            }

            cvs.Add(new SortDescription("Name", ListSortDirection.Ascending));

            _view = cvs.View;
        }

        return _view;
    }
}
```

As you can see, the code where the query exists is not what is directly bound to the UI.  I use this example to demonstrate that I am asking from a more general use-case than strictly a UI data-binding scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this (assuming an ObservableCollection called observable and class implementing INotifyPropertyChanged with RaisePropertyChanged method):

```
public IEnumerable<string> NewList
{
    return from item in observable
           select item.Name;
}

observable.CollectionChanged += delegate { RaisePropertyChanged("NewList"); };
```

Then the when observable is changed, the UI will be told that NewList has changed to and re-evaluate the query.

For multiple dependent items you can do:

```
observable.CollectionChanged += delegate
    {
        RaisePropertyChanged("NewList",
                             "OtherProperty",
                             "YetAnotherProperty",
                             "Etc");
    };
```

**Update**

The above works fine in general for properties, as you will get the latest value every time you access it and INPC can be used to tell things to re-read it.

For the slightly more interesting case of collections, I would implement a custom class that implements INotifyCollectionChanged and IEnumerable and wraps the LINQ.  E.g.,

```
public class CustomObservableCollection<T> : INotifyCollectionChanged,
                                             INotifyPropertyChanged,
                                             IEnumerable<T>
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<T> _collection;
    public CustomObservableCollection(IEnumerable<T> collection)
    {
        _collection = collection;
    }
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        _collection.GetEnumerator();
    }
    public void RaiseCollectionChanged() { ... }
    ...
}
```

Then you can do:

```
var newList = new CustomObservableCollection(from item in observable
                                             select item.Name);
observable.CollectionChanged += delegate { newList.RaiseCollectionChanged(); };
```

**Update 2**

You could even pass the dependency to CustomObservableCollection:

```
public class CustomObservableCollection<T> : INotifyCollectionChanged,
                                             INotifyPropertyChanged,
                                             IEnumerable<T>
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<T> _collection;
    public CustomObservableCollection(IEnumerable<T> collection,
                 params ObservableCollection[] dependencies)
    {
        _collection = collection;
        foreach (var dep in dependencies)
            dep.CollectionChanged += RaiseCollectionChanged();
    }
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        _collection.GetEnumerator();
    }
    public void RaiseCollectionChanged() { ... }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yea, this works when the resulting collection is directly bound to the UI which is only one use-case. I'm looking for a more general solution that covers other uses as well.  See my update.

Comment: WRT your update, I don't see how CustomObservableCollection receives notifications when the original collection (observable) changes. Please elaborate if you have more in mind because all you've shown is what is already available using ObservableCollection.

Comment: The addition is the ability to manually fire the update and hence put it in the delegate in the last line.  Also, ObservableCollection makes a copy of the list, whereas this keeps the original LINQ.

Comment: You could, of course, pass observable to CustomObservableCollection and setup the event handling internally.

Comment: Keep in mind that when the original ObservableCollection changes, the LINQ statement must be re-evaluted to determine the new result set. It's not as simple as bubbling the changed event.

Comment: Take the case where a new Employee is hired. A new item is added to _allEmployees which raises its changed event. The Where clause needs to be re-evaluated so that CurrentEmployees is updated with the new Employee.  Similarly, if an Employee is fired, CurrentEmployees should be updated as well.

Comment: I've expanded the example a bit more to make it clearer that that is what is happening.  As the underlying IEnumerable is LINQ, it is re-evaluated every time you access it.  The collection change notification just tells observers that it has changed (which is essentially just when the dependencies are changed as it is bound to the collectionchanged event of the dependencies).

Comment: Ah, I see what you are getting at.  Let me give it a try and see how it works!

Comment: Great suggestions.  See my response below for how I took your advice and implemented my solution. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just bind directly to `observable`, and select the properties you want.

e.g.:

```
public IEnumerable<Item> Items { get { return this.observable;} }

<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: I think the OP was after the general case for anything that depends on observable, rather than just properties of observable.

Comment: As I said to @Scroog1, the case where the resulting collection is directly bound to the UI is only one use-case and I've updated the original post as that is not the crux of my question. I'm looking for a more general solution.

Comment: As for your specific response, @Scroog1 is correct that this solution is also limited to simple projection cases, which was also not what I was really after.

Answer (score 0):

As I referenced in the comments to Scroog1's answer, I was able to take his answer and modify it slightly to use in my application.  I ended up with a wrapper class that accepts the original collection, a predicate and a selector function as constructor arguments, as shown here:

```
public class ObservableWrapper<TSource, TElement> : IEnumerable<TElement>,
                                                    INotifyCollectionChanged
{
    private Collection<TElement> _items;
    private Func<TSource, Boolean> _predicate;
    private Func<TSource, TElement> _selector;
    private ObservableCollection<TSource> _source;

    public ObservableWrapper(ObservableCollection<TSource> source,
                             Func<TSource, Boolean> predicate,
                             Func<TSource, TElement> selector)
    {
        _predicate = predicate;
        _selector = selector;
        _source = source;

        _source.CollectionChanged += SourceCollectionChanged;
    }

    public IEnumerator<TElement> GetEnumerator()
    {
        EnsureItems();

        return _items.GetEnumerator();
    }

    private void EnsureItems()
    {
        if (_items == null)
        {
            _items = new Collection<TElement>();

            RefreshItems();
        }
    }

    private void NotifyCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction action)
    {
        var handlers = CollectionChanged;

        if (handlers != null)
        {
            var args = new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(action);

            handlers(this, args);
        }
    }

    private void RefreshItems()
    {
        _items.Clear();

        foreach (var element in _source)
        {
            if (_predicate(element))
            {
                var item = _selector(element);

                _items.Add(item);
            }
        }

        NotifyCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset);
    }

    private void SourceCollectionChanged(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        RefreshItems();
    }

    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

My original example becomes:

```
var newList = new ObservableWrapper<Person, Char>(observable,
                                                  item => { return true; },
                                                  item => { return item.Name[0]; });
```

The downside is that the projection is unnamed.  But, in more complex scenarios, I simply define TElement as a class and return that from the selector function.